# can any one tell me how to access my parsed xml object

Tags: soap, xml-namespaces

i have this parsed object 
            $xmlObj = new SimpleXMLElement($XMLToParse, LIBXML_DOTTED_VERSION, FALSE, "http://SOME/schema/universal_v17_0");

that has the stucture like this inside it

```
                 <universal:UniversalR LocatorCode="somecode" Version="2" Status="Active">

<common_v17_0:Book Key="some" TravelerType="some">
```

so i can access the first element(its attributes) like this $VariableX=$xmlObj->UniversalR->attributes();//then $VariableX["Status"];
but when i want access his child i cant $tm=$xmlObj->UniversalR->Book->attributes(); 
it doesnt want to enter probably because of the different namespace...can any one help me . THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something here http://blog.sherifmansour.com/?p=302

```
    foreach ($xmlObj->UniversalRecord as $entry){


      $namespaces = $entry->getNameSpaces(true);

       $cmm = $entry->->children($namespaces['common_v17_0']); 
    $aa=$cmm->Book->attributes();
    echo $aa["TravelerType"]."ddddd";

}
```

That should do it :)

Answer (score 0):

`$tm=$xmlObj->UniversalRecord->Book->attributes();` is this typo (UniversalRecord instead of UniversalR) only present in this post or is it also present in your code?
(I'd have liked to post this as a comment.. but it looks like i'm not allowed to, or am too stupid to find the button. :/)